# Java Application Debugging Using Eclipse Scrapbook

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, testing, junit

I have a Java application  with several (10) packages and almost 50 classes. My task is to understand the application (with poor documentation and no test cases). The application seem to have several bugs that I need to correct. So, I have started reverse engineering it and developing test cases based on the understanding. At times, I am using the test cases to understand the application itself. In this process , I am using JUnit test suit. I am also using the Eclipse Scrapbook, which to me is a very handy tool. I am testing small snippets of code using the scrapbook. As there are several packages and classes, I want to preserve all the small tests that I am doing using the scrapbook. My question is regarding the organization of the scrapbook(s) for large applications and the common practice. Is it a common practice to create separate scrapbooks (like Junit test case for each class and methods) for each package ? I am looking for guidelines that is followed in industry.